# query for max values among subcollections in firestore

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to add Leaderboard to my app in which it will show the 50 top-ranked users.

My firestore is built as follows:

USERS (collections) -> UID (document) -> UserData (collection) -> UID (document) -> fields

one of the fields is called rank.

Now, I had like to perform something like that:

```
db
    .collection( "USERS" )
    .document(UID)
    .collection("UserData")
    .document(UID)
    .orderBy( "rank", Query.Direction.DESCENDING )
    .limit( 50)
    .get()
```

But I know it is not going to work since it will query the specific document and not the whole collection of USERS.

Is there any way to search what is the rank of each user without going into each document and get that value? Or do I have to change the structure of the database?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query documents among all subcollections of the same name, you would want to do a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which you can use to find and sort all documents within those subcollections.

```
db
    .collectionGroup("UserData")
    .orderBy( "rank", Query.Direction.DESCENDING )
    .limit( 50)
    .get()
```

Comment: Can it query straight from UserData even without going through USERS->specific document UID? because I tried it and it seems like it doesnt return any result.

Comment: That's what this query is doing - going straight to all subcollections with the given name.  You should also check for errors, as you'd have to create an index for this, and the query will fail without one.

Comment: Missed the indexing thing. Thanks mate